# does spring implements jsr 303 or it is a extended specification

Tags: validation, hibernate-validator, jsr, spring-validator

I am confused that if spring validation just supports the jsr 303 or spring validation is a implementation of jsr 303 like hibernate-validator or apache-validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not provide implementation but as per Spring
"With JSR-303, a single javax.validation.Validator instance typically validates all model objects that declare validation constraints. To configure a JSR-303-backed Validator with Spring MVC, simply add a JSR-303 Provider, such as Hibernate Validator, to your classpath. Spring MVC will detect it and automatically enable JSR-303 support across all Controllers"

More details ca be found at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-jsr303